# Using input function in Scilab prompt user multiple times

Tags: input, prompt, scilab

so I'm learning the basics of Scilab and i was trying to figure out how the Input function works but i keep getting a bizarre problem.

Here's my code:

```
    A = input("Enter value of A: ")
    B = input("Enter value of B: ")
    disp("The value of A is: " +string(A))
    disp("The value of B is: " +string(B))
```

And This's what i get:

```
   Enter value of A: 
   6
   Enter value of A: 
   --> 5
   Enter value of A: 
   5



  Enter value of B: 
  8


   The value of A is: 5

   The value of B is: 8
```

I have no idea why i was prompted 3 times to enter the value of A.
A lil bit of help understanding this please, thank you.

Comment: Works as expected in my Scilab 5.5.1. Is the above really all of the code you have, or was it inside of something else?

Comment: @NormalHuman It's all the code i have, and this happens pretty much all the time whenever i use more than one input.

Comment: Tried on Scilab 5.4.1 too, and works as expected. Have you tried to restart Scilab, or restart your computer? What version of Scilab do you use?

Comment: @Attila I tried all of what you mentioned, i even uninstalled it and installed it again but  still the same problem. I'm using scilab 6.0.0.

Comment: Maybe you should also try a 5.x.x version instead. Newer versions may have more advanced features, but the pobability of newly introduced bugs is much higher between major version changes. Thus newer is not always better...

Comment: @Attila Thank you, I'll try that and see how it'll work

Comment: @SiMohamed The same thing is happening to me too. Im also using scilab 6.0.0. In fact I just googled the problem to find a soution and I stumbled upon you question. I also used input command twice and the prompt asks multiple times for the same input. Guess its a scilab bug rather than coding error from our side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually a bug brought by Scilab 6.
It is fixed for years now (@https://gitlab.com/scilab/scilab/-/issues/14424 )